# Can I dynamically populate a form field in Google forms?

Tags: google-forms

I would like to pass a parameter into my form which automatically populates one of the fields with that value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to send respondents a form with some fields already filled in, Google Forms makes it easy. Here's how to pre-populate form answer fields:

1. While working on your form, click the Responses menu, then select Get pre-filled URL.
2. Fill in any answer fields you'd like to pre-populate.
3. Click Submit.
4. To send the pre-populated form to respondents, use the URL provided.

Taken from: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160000?hl=en

You should be able to dynamically tweak the values in the URL provided.

Comment: Hi Gadget, thanks for your answer, however this deals with pre-populating static content. Instead, I would like to populate dynamic content from a parameter.

Comment: Ahhh ok. Is the form publicly available? Are you able to provide a link to the form?